# how to call external class to controller in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twitter, controller

how to include this code in my controler ?
do i have to create directory into vendor or something like this ?

```
require_once('twitter-sdk/twitteroauth.php');


$consumerKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$accessTokenSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$message = "je suis entrain de tester quelque chose"; // Message à tweeter : doit contenir moins de 140 caractères


$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
$res = $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create directory in your bundle namespace - like TwitterOAuth/ and create there two php files: first one wuth TwitterOAuth class definition and the second one with authentication logic (it might be called TwitterOAuthProvider or something). Put into both of them proper namespaces.

TwitterOAuth:

```
<?php
namespace YourBundleNamespace\TwitterOAuth;

class TwitterOAuth {
// twitteroauth implementation
}
```

TwitterOAuthProvider:

```
<?php
namespace YourBundleNamespace\TwitterOAuth;
class TwitterOAuthProvider
{
    public function authenticate()
    {
        // here is authentication logic
    }
}
```

And then you can register you second class as service:

```
twitter_oauth_provider:
    class: YourBundleNamespace\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthProvider
```

And call it from controller like this:

```
$this->get('twitter_oauth_provider')->authenticate();
```

Comment: if i put my twitterOath in vendor/component what's my BundleNamespace

Comment: No, don't do that. In vendor directory should be placed code which might be retrievied from packagist by composer. You can upload it to packagist, but I think you don't need it. It's better in your case to keep it in your bundle (it's absolutely evident that vendor/ is not a good place for that).

Answer (score 0):

May be like this?:

add `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, ...  to `paramters.yml` file, create a directory in your bundle's root directiry, for ex, `Component`, copy `twitter-sdk` into it, create a service class, register it:

```
class TwitterSDKManager
{
    private $consumerKey;
    private $consumerSecret;
    private $accessToken;
    private $accessTokenSecret;
    private $message;

    public function __construct($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret)
    {
        $this->consumerKey = $consumerKey;
        $this->consumerSecret = $consumerSecret;
        ...
    }

    public function getOAuth()
    {
        return new TwitterOAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret, $this->accessToken, $this->accessTokenSecret);
    }

    ...
}
```

service config:

```
...

<parameter key="twitter_sdk.manager.class">Vendor\MyBundle\Manager\TwitterSDKManager</parameter>

....

<service id="twitter_sdk.manager" class="%twitter_sdk.manager.class%">
    <argument key='consumerKey'>%consumerKey%</argument>
    <argument key='consumerSecret'>%consumerSecret%</argument>
    ....
</service>
...
```

usage (for ex, in controller):

```
$tweet = $this->get('twitter_sdk.manager')->getOAuth();

$res = $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Message'));
print_r($res);
```

Comment: do i have to create the class TwitterSDKManager inside my directory twitter-sdk ? and where i can find the service config file